# Bash: execute and print command as I'd write it in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell, echo

Having executed:

```
cd ~ && mkdir mytmp && cd mytmp/
echo > somefile
```

and doing this in a bash script **mytmp/myscript.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# version 1
cmd="find . -type f -printf %f\n"
$cmd
```

renders the wanted result, i.e.:

```
somefile
myscript.sh
```

Notice that for some reason I don't need to surround %f\n with quotes as I'd do it if I were to write the command in the terminal. Doing so would render a bad result:

```
#!/bin/bash
# version 2
cmd="find . -type f -printf '%f\n'"
$cmd
```

results in:

```
'somefile
''myscript.sh
'
```

I need to **execute** $cmd *and* at the same time print it as I'd write it in the **terminal**.

Adding `echo $cmd` in `version 1` executes the command properly but echoes the command without quotes.

Adding `echo $cmd` in `version 2` echoes the command with quotes, like I want, but the result of command execution is bad.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could `set -x` `set +x` could make it ?

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) *now*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had the answer to this question, but since I "accidentally" got what I wanted and haven't found the answer online after searching for it, I thought I'd post it here anyway.

The solution is including the quotes as in `version 2` and getting rid of them when executing the command by using **eval**:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="find . -type f -printf '%f\n'"
eval $cmd
echo $cmd
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21)

Comment: Hi, just read it, not very attentively as I don't have the time now, but what I got is that if I want to execute a command I should directly execute it or put it into a function if I need it repeatedly executed, instead of putting it into a variable. But that doesn't tell me what I must do when I want to also **echo** the command?

Answer (score 1):

Use `set -v`.

#### Example Script

I used some overly complicated script, to test the output for quoting and so on.

```
#! /bin/bash
set -v
myVariable='test'
# a comment
echo "$(echo "$myVariable") two" | cat -
```

#### Output When Running The Script

```
$ ./myscript
```

```
myVariable='test'
# a comment
echo "$(echo "$myVariable") two" | cat -
echo "$myVariable"
test two
```

As we can see, quotes, variable names, and comments are retained, but commands from subshells will appear twice. Since you don't use any subshells, that shouldn't be a problem.